# How to responsively place links in a navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with CSS at the moment. I'm working on a navbar with some horizontal links and a dropdown menu at the end.

The links collapse into a hamburger menu when on a small screen. What I'm trying to do is, when the links collapse, I want the last link that is next to the dropdown button to be placed after the dropdown button.

Here is what it looks like when uncollapsed and with the dropdown open:

[image]

This is what it looks like collapsed at the moment:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to look:

[image]

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I have tried floating the "Profile name" to the right and it kinda works as it place itself to the right of the "IMG" but then all the way to the right. I would like it placed snug to the "IMG". Padding it to the right place screws up the responsiveness.

I'm using bootstrap for the responsiveness and dropdown menu. I assume that I will have to use media queries for this.

If anyone has any idea of how to do this I am more than grateful for any tip!

here is a code

```html
<ul>
  <li class="horizontal-align">Link 1</li>
  <li class="horizontal-align">Link 2</li>
  <li class="horizontal-align">Profile name</li>
  <li class="horizontal-align"> <img class="Profile-img" />
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-li">Link 3</li>
      <li class="dropdown-li">Link 4</li>
      <li class="dropdown-li">Link 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*Keeping the dropdown open while in hamburger-mode is a problem for another day.*

Comment: Got any code snippets of what you have tried? HTML, CSS.. etc.

Comment: Can you please include your code, and preferably make a snippet / demo. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgott! Here is a simplified version of the HTML if it helps.

Comment: try some framework like foundation or bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

so simply write this way

`<li class="horizontal-align"> <img class="Profile-img"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg"/>Profile name`

```css
.Profile-img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="horizontal-align">LinkLink 1</li>
  <li class="horizontal-align">Link 2</li>
  <li class="horizontal-align"> <img class="Profile-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" />Profile name
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-li">Link 3</li>
      <li class="dropdown-li">Link 4</li>
      <li class="dropdown-li">Link 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thing is, I would like to keep it the way it is when uncollapsed

Answer (score 0):

check the bootstrap 4 official documentation. I used it yesterday for a navbar and it works great with the responsive. 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/
if you want to include bootstrap 4 in your code, add this to the head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I would love to upgrade to bootstrap 4 but our product owner has requested us to use bootstrap 3.

Comment: for the navbar there's no problem, i also used examples from bootstrap 3 and it worked fine. W3schools still has examples in bootstrap 3 if i remember right. Check it https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. Solution was embarrassingly  simple. I wrapped profile name and img in a div and set it to width: fit-content. Then when changing the float on the profile name to right with media queries, it positioned itself right next to the img.

Thanks for the responses though!